# Stuck in the Do-While loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop, do-while

```
Boolean answer = true;
while(answer == true){
    String ans;

    do{
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to enter another student's record?
        (Enter Y or N)");
        ans = in.next().toUpperCase();
        }
        while((!ans.equals("Y")) || (!ans.equals("N")));
        in.close();

        if(ans.equals("Y")){
            answer = true;
        } //End of YES if statement   

        else{
            answer = false;
        } //End of NO statement

    } //End of While Statement for Main program
```

**Okay a brief description of the obvious: I set the program on a loop based on if "answer = true". However, the do-while loop doesn't seem to accept "Y" or "N" and continues looping. Why does this code not work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
(!ans.equals("Y")) || (!ans.equals("N"))
```

into this :

```
(!ans.equals("Y")) && (!ans.equals("N")))
```

That's why you were stuck !

Answer (score 2):

`(!ans.equals("Y")) || (!ans.equals("N"))` is always true

You might want to use `while((!ans.equals("Y")) && (!ans.equals("N")));`