# C programming while condition being ignored

Tags: c, while-loop

My second while condition is being ignored and not sure how to fix it.

```
int while_counter = 0;
int finish_flag = 0; 
while(while_counter < 100 || finish_flag != 1)
{
    while_counter++;
    finish_flag = 1;
    printf(" finish_flag is %d \n", finish_flag);
}
```

I'm guessing its interpreting it as. Right? How would I fix this? I still want my first condition to be respected.

```
while(1)
{
    while_counter++;
    finish_flag = 1;
    printf(" finish_flag is %d \n", finish_flag);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want || here and not &&?

Comment: `||` is a short circuiting operator, if the left hand side is true the right hand side is never evaluated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ignored"?

Comment: Your condition is not ignored. `finish_flag` is set to `1` on the first iteration of the loop, which means that it will execute only once, as the whole expression `(while_counter < 100 || finish_flag != 1)` is true only once - before the first iteration.

Comment: Voting to close due to `finish_flag = 1;` in the loop. Either a typo or misdesigned algorithm, or misunderstanding of the basics.

Comment: @Vality I would like it to break when while_counter hits 100 or when finish_flag gets set to 1. Would switching to && fix this?

Comment: Seriously people, this is high-shcool algebra. A simple De Morgan rule: `not (A or B) == not A and not B`. Like, no one grasps this? [Q #26453884](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453884/stuck-in-the-do-while-loop)

Comment: @shuttle87 Would switching my two case around fix my issue?

Comment: @Codor It prints `finish_flag is 1` 99 times so it is not breaking out of the while loop.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar run a simple program with this. It does not break out on the first iteration.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl my while loop is over 300 lines of code. I chose to give a simple example of what I was doing.

Comment: I think it is not being ignored but the first condition is true for all of the iterations

Comment: @coolstuff, switching the order of the `||` operator won't change the logic of your loop. You need to rewrite the logic in the while condition to make it do what you want. The previous comment about De Morgans laws is fairly spot on here.

Comment: I just knew from the title......

Comment: @MartinJames be nice ;). You were new at programming at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Logical AND operator instead of the Logical OR operator.

In english,read the condition in `while` as:
"**while `while_counter` <100 or `finish_flag` is not 1, Do everything in my body**".

Think about in for a moment . You will realize you need to replace "or" with "and" in the english version above and this is why you need `&&` instead of `||`.

In your current version, both of the conditions in the `while` needs to be false in order for it to end. You modify `finish_flag`, making the second condition false but increment `while_condition` once every iteration.
Since `||` means "or" only one of the arguments need to be true in order for the body to execute. So,`while_condition` needs to increment 100 times for the first condition to be `false` and this is why the loop executed 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation (while(1)) is not right.
Your code will print "finish_flag is 1" 100 times. If it was while(1), it would print "finish_flag is 1" forever.

Can't figure out what exactly you are looking to do here.

```
while(while_counter < 100 || finish_flag != 1)
{
    while_counter++;
    finish_flag = 1;
    printf(" finish_flag is %d \n", finish_flag);
}
```

Explaining much here would be useless, unless you explain what you need exactly.